# fullcalendar stops showing events after more than 10k events

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

Hi I want to use fullcalendar with a database its works but as soon as I put more than 10k events in the calendar it stops showing events. 
Is there a way to stop fullcalendar from stopping to show events?

The version below is 4.0.0
(I used both 3.9.0 and 4.0.0 of fullcalendar both are not working)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { // DOMContentLoaded zorgt ervoor dat eerst de html laad
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar'); // grab element reference

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            // put your options and callbacks here
            events: [
                <?php

                include_once('./assets/handlers/DB_Handler.php');

                try {
                    $getCalenderItems = $conn->prepare("SELECT COD.CursusID, O.Onderdeelnaam,
                    CONCAT( REPLACE( DATE_ADD( DATE( CO.DatumBegin ) , INTERVAL -1 MONTH ) ,  '-',  ',' ) ,  ',', HOUR( CO.DatumBegin ) ,  ',', MINUTE( CO.DatumBegin ) ) AS Start,
                    CONCAT( REPLACE( DATE_ADD( DATE( CO.DatumEind ) , INTERVAL -1 MONTH ) ,  '-',  ',' ) ,  ',', HOUR( CO.DatumEind ) ,  ',', MINUTE( CO.DatumEind ) ) AS Eind

                    FROM cursusonderdeeldocenten COD

                    INNER JOIN onderdelen O ON COD.OnderdeelID = O.OnderdeelID
                    INNER JOIN cursusonderdelen CO ON COD.CursusID = CO.CursusID

                    WHERE COD.DocentID = 15
                    AND CO.DatumBegin >=  DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -8 MONTH)
                    ORDER BY CO.DatumBegin");

                    $getCalenderItems->bindParam(':DocentID', $DiD);

                    // Select docent
                    $DiD = 15;
                    $getCalenderItems->execute();
                    $count = $getCalenderItems->rowCount();

                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    $e->getMessage();
                }

                $i = 0;

                while ($row = $getCalenderItems->fetch()) {

                    echo '
                                                        {
                                                        title: "' . $row['Onderdeelnaam'] . '",
                                                        start: new Date(' . $row['Start'] . '),
                                                        end: new Date(' . $row['Eind'] . '),
                                                        url: "./beoordelen/' . $row['CursusID'] . '"
                                                        }';

                    if ($i >= $count) {
                        echo "";
                    } else {
                        echo ",";
                    }

                    $i++;
                }

                ?>
            ]
        });

        calendar.render();
    });
</script>
<div id='calendar'></div>


</div>
```

Comment: any console errors? that is really a huge number of events, maybe it simply can't cope with the volume, or it's just taking a very long time to process them.

Comment: P.S. It seems you are trying to load 8 months worth of events at once? That's unnecessary. If, instead of injectig your events into the JavaScript code, you specify your events as a feed URL which accepts start and end dates as input parameters (and which just returns the events between those dates as JSON), then fullCalendar will just go and fetch the events for the necessary time period, if and when the user views that time period. If they never look at that month, it never bothers to load them. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed

Answer (score 0):

I added 3k+ events to my calendar and it works fine. You can check my code [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/iLtc/deb33bb2486d9ec3e7fd2a430e12caf2/raw/bffa51dc03d2cb45b9bf1f5b11bc6d87fb8432fd/FullCalendarDemo.py).

Could you check the browser console to see if there is an error?

The version that I use is 3.9.0.

Comment: Ok so it does work when i delete title and url from the $row fetch but these are important is there any other way to load the data?

Comment: @RubenvandeBunt I added title and URL, and it still works. Can you provide the HTML code your program generated and we can see what's going on there?